# Tratando Query Many-to-Many

Tags: php, mysql, relacionamento

Fiquei numa dúvida sobre relacionamento Many-to-Many e espero não estar fazendo uma pergunta repetida, mas não encontrei a solução para minha dúvida em canto nenhum.

Acontece que eu tenho uma tabela de imagens, uma tabela de trabalhos e uma tabela de relacionamento que faz um relacionamento Many-to-Many entre as duas primeiras.

Cada trabalho pode ter várias imagens relacionadas a ele. Então eu fiz um query da seguinte maneira:

```
select jobs.*, f1.file_name, f2.file_name 
from jobs 
    left JOIN photos_per_job p ON p.job_id = jobs.id
    left JOIN fotos f1 on p.photo_id = f1.id 
    inner join fotos f2 on jobs.foto_capa = f2.id
```

E obtive o resultado abaixo:

[image: resultado da query]

O meu problema agora é organizar essas informações no view. Se vocês notarem bem o trabalho que possui três fotos se repete no resultado três vezes, mas quando eu for mostrar os trabalhos para o usuário eu vou mostrar um trabalho por vez e cada trabalho vai ter sua série de fotos.

Há alguma maneira de organizar o resultado de uma forma que facilite meu laço na view ou para organizar isso melhor eu preciso trabalhar o próprio laço?

Comment: Poderia postar como está feita estas três tabelas separadamente? Seria mais fácil para compreender. De onde vem essas imagens?

Comment: Como isso deve ser apresentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode implementar essa lógica no próprio **PHP**, altere o seu select assim:

```
SELECT jobs.*, f1.file_name, f2.file_name AS nome_foto_capa 
from jobs 
    LEFT JOIN photos_per_job p ON p.job_id = jobs.id
    LEFT JOIN fotos f1 on p.photo_id = f1.id 
    INNER JOIN fotos f2 on jobs.foto_capa = f2.id
```

Utilize este codigo PHP para tratar o resultado do banco:

```
$trabalhos = array();
/* LAÇO QUE PERCORRE OS RESULTADOS RETORNADO PELO MYSQL (PODE SUBSTIRUIR PELO QUE VOCE UTILIZA)*/
foreach($results as $row){
    if(!isset($trabalhos[$row['id']])){
        $trabalhos[$row['id']] = array(
            'id' => $row['id'], 
            'titulo' => $row['titulo'], 
            'foto_capa' => $row['foto_capa'], 
            'descricao' => $row['descricao'], 
            'bg_color' => $row['bg_color'], 
            'font_color' => $row['font_color'], 
            'time' => $row['time'], 
            'nome_foto_capa' => $row['nome_foto_capa']
        );
    }
    $trabalhos[$row['id']]['fotos'][] = $row['file_name'];  
}
```

---

Ou então voce pode agrupar o nome das fotos usando o **GRUOUP_CONCAT**, assim o nome das fotos 
vão aparecer concatenadas somente em um campo separados por virgula, depois e so dar um explode pela virgula.
Mas dependendo da quantidade de fotos não recomendo usar essa abordagem, pois **GROUP_CONCAT** tem um limite de caracteres.

```
SELECT jobs.*, GROUP_CONCAT(f1.file_name) AS fotos, f2.file_name AS nome_foto_capa 
from jobs 
    LEFT JOIN photos_per_job p ON p.job_id = jobs.id
    LEFT JOIN fotos f1 on p.photo_id = f1.id 
    INNER JOIN fotos f2 on jobs.foto_capa = f2.id
GROUP BY jobs.id
```

Comment: Nossa, cara. Era isso que eu estava precisando. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você tem de agrupa-la.

Faça algo assim:

```
select jobs.*, f1.file_name, f2.file_name 
from jobs j 
    left JOIN photos_per_job p ON p.job_id = j.id
    left JOIN fotos f1 on p.photo_id = f1.id 
    inner join fotos f2 on j.foto_capa = f2.id
 group by j.id, j.titulo, j.foto_capa, j.descricao, j.bg_color,
   j.font_color, j.time, f2.file_name
```

Comment: Vai continuar trazendo o mesmo resultado, o campo f1.file_name e diferente nas 3 primeiras linhas e o j.id diferente nos últimos.

Comment: Certo. Não notei que eram diferentes. Nesse caso tem de retirar esse campo do select, senão não poderá obter o resultado que ele espera.

Comment: E no select ? jobs.*, f1.file_name,?

Comment: Não dar para fazer um group by para trazer tudo certinho sem entender a estrutura das tabelas.

Comment: Concordo com você. Por isso que eu disse "faça algo assim", querendo dizer "algo parecido com isso".